# AdBlock Plus exception filter not working

Tags: firefox, adblock

I have an AdBlock Plus exception filter (shown below) I am using in Firefox 39.0 and it still seems to be blocking the script:

[image: Adblock Plus exception problem]

As you can see by the green-colored text it should be whitelisting that particular file (banner_ads.js), but nevertheless the file is still getting blocked. What am I doing wrong? Is it a bug?

Tooltip text:

[image: adblock tooltip]

Comment: I see you're also using another script blocking add-on but sc2casts.com is allowed. Are there any other such add-ons that you are using? I would suggest testing them one at a time to know where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @MC10 The only AddOn is NoScript which has the whole page white listed. The problem is with AdBlock.

Comment: When you hover over the green circle on the right, does it say something like allow non-intrusive advertising or did you add an exception rule for that file? What do you use to track if it was downloaded or not, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?

Comment: @MC10 I have added a screenshot showing the tootip text that pops up when hovering over the green circle.

Comment: Okay, I have set mine up the same way now. What is the script supposed to be doing on the page and what is going wrong?

Comment: Just look at the script, it sets a variable. The variable is not getting set. AdBlock is blocking the script even though it is whitelisted, just as the question says.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26370/discussion-between-mc10-and-tyler-durden).